# How to traverse every second node in a circular linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

In a for loop while traversing an array I can traverse every second index of the array with a loop variable increment of two. But how can I use any loop to visit every second node in a circular linked list? I assume I can traverse each node from any direction but what I want to do is if a-b-c-d-e-a is a circular linked list I want to traverse like a-c-e-b-d-a-c- ... like this...

Comment: You mean perform some operation on `a`, then `c`, and so on? Or go from `a` to `c` without querying `b` in any way?

Comment: how can it be  without querying b? @Beta

Comment: @Beta I mean to perform some operation on a then c and so on...and I don't to query b as I don't have any operation on b.

Comment: Start at `a`. Perform the operation. Advance the pointer (to `b`). Advance the pointer again (to `c`). Perform the operation. And so on. Is that satisfactory?

Comment: @Beta can i do it with a loop or something...or automate it....what it I choose a step size 3...like a-d-b- ... so on...

Comment: What do you mean? Input 3, and iterate how? A - D - B? or A - C - B?

Comment: I want to take a step size...that means if a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j-a is my circular linked list then if my step size is 3 then it should iterate like a-d-g-j-c-f-i-b- ... so on and if the step size is 2 it should iterate like a-c-e-g-i-a-c- ... so on..

Comment: `p = p->next->next;`  General solution `for (i=0;i<stepSize;i++) p = p->next;`

Comment: @quidstone Please add code that you already have (traversing one by one)

Comment: @anatolyg It can be done and loop can be broken for some external condition.

Comment: @quidstone I am not sure I expressed that adequately. What I mean is: to make sure people understand what exactly you are asking, you should add your existing code to your question. This will help you, because maybe someone will take your code and do the necessary changes in order to answer your question. This seems important, because you got an answer that you didn't comment or accept, so maybe the person who asked misunderstood your question.

Comment: @anatolyg heres the link of my code...its a josephus problem...i created the circular linked list and now i want to traverse it....TLE is not the headache...i want this to work right now...https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a9a9176b19f64d165817

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but in any case, you can simply move to each second node by using the node's next next pointer (and / or previous previous pointer if it's doubly linked).

You can do this in a loop like so;

```
loop (condition) {
     traveler = traveler->next->next;

     // Do something with node
     ...
}
```

Here, your `traveler` node is simply a dummy node that traverses the list.

Because your linked list is circular, your `condition` must be such that you need to find some way of terminating the loop instead of detecting if the next node (`traveler`) is `NULL`.

Comment: if step size is two it is traveler->next->next.....and if step size =3 is it traveler->next->next->next?

and if i want a variable step size what do i do?

Comment: @quidstone - I'm not going to show you the code, but if you want to vary the step size, a recursive function will do the trick. All you need to do is pass your step size and current node into the function. You'll then have a counter incrementing as you move to the next node and once you've reach your step size, return a pointer to that node. Good luck.